# Python SqlAlchemy Order by closest date

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, backend

I have a MySQL database and I need to send the client some data from my tables, the client need to get the closest event date but without getting all of the date  (using pagination which is already in place and working fine)... 
So I need to provide the client with the closest events by date first, there are some events in the future and some in the past (the client will get all of them by pagination) so order_by is not good enough by it's own.

I'm using this:
events = session.query(Event).filter(user.userID == userID).order_by(desc('eventDate')

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: If two dates are separated by the same difference.  which should come first?

Answer (score 0):

[Working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a320c/3/0)

Sort by the absolute value of a date diff in days from current date? substitute current date for date selected by user if needed

```
Create table foo(
  ID int,
  eventDate date);

Insert into foo (ID, eventDate)
values (1,'2017-01-01'),
(2,'2017-01-02'),
(3,'2017-01-03'),
(4,'2017-01-04'),
(5,'2017-01-05'),
(6,'2017-01-06'),
(7,'2017-01-07'),
(8,'2017-01-08'),
(9,'2017-01-09');


SELECT * 
FROM foo
ORDER BY abs(dateDiff(eventDate,'2017-01-05')), EventDate
```

Returns:

```
ID  eventDate
5   January, 05 2017 00:00:00
4   January, 04 2017 00:00:00
6   January, 06 2017 00:00:00
3   January, 03 2017 00:00:00
7   January, 07 2017 00:00:00
2   January, 02 2017 00:00:00
8   January, 08 2017 00:00:00
1   January, 01 2017 00:00:00
9   January, 09 2017 00:00:00
```